# Updating/Removing an ActiveRecord AREL query parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I want to be able to remove a condition from an active record query.

The scenario I have is:

Through the ui the user selects a number of records, and does a bulk update.

(resulting in an AREL query, and then update_all call).

I would then like to send an email notifying relevant people of the updated records.

When the update updates attributes in the original query this doesn't work for me as the data changes and no longer works.  So my question is, Is it possible to update the AREL query and remove conditions?

Comment: Asking the question led me to almost finding the answer.  I've found that I can manipulate the where values hash on the relation.  Does that sound completely wrong?

Comment: Can't you build a new query instead of altering old one?